# How to trigger red squigglies with UltraSpellChecker without user intervention?

Tags: infragistics, spell-checking

The Infragistics docs say to set Mode to AsYouType and when the user types a space the spell checker will create the squigglies.

I also see there is an [AsYouTypeManager](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawinspellchecker%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawinspellchecker.asyoutypemanager) class but don't know where or how to use it either. The documentation online is not that great.

When a box is loaded with the data and it has errors, I would like to have the red squigglies appear without any user interaction. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows how the `UltraSpellChecker` must be initialized to have the red squiggles appear without any user interaction.

**Form1.cs**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The extender property must be set for the rich text box so that it may be spell checked. 
    // This can also be done through the property grid in the forms designer
    this.ultraSpellChecker1.SetSpellCheckerSettings(this.rtbSpellChecked, new SpellCheckerSettings(true));
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.rtbSpellChecked = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    this.ultraSpellChecker1 = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSpellChecker.UltraSpellChecker(this.components);
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ultraSpellChecker1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // rtbSpellChecked
    // 
    this.rtbSpellChecked.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.rtbSpellChecked.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.rtbSpellChecked.Name = "rtbSpellChecked";
    this.rtbSpellChecked.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(411, 266);
    this.rtbSpellChecked.TabIndex = 5;
    this.rtbSpellChecked.Text = "UltraSpellChecker Class\nPerforms spel cheking on one or more conrols.";
    // 
    // ultraSpellChecker1
    // 
    this.ultraSpellChecker1.ContainingControl = this;
    this.ultraSpellChecker1.Mode = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSpellChecker.SpellCheckingMode.AsYouType;
    this.ultraSpellChecker1.ShowDialogsModal = false;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(411, 266);
    this.Controls.Add(this.rtbSpellChecked);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "UltraSpellChecker";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ultraSpellChecker1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion

private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSpellChecker.UltraSpellChecker ultraSpellChecker1;
private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbSpellChecked;
```

The `this.ultraSpellChecker1.Mode` is set to `SpellCheckingMode.AsYouType` as described in the Infragistics documentation and the code above shows the following form:

[image]